# Can anyone here read old scripts? (Characters Identified: 松月侣)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Hello I have a bronze censer with the mark below on the bottom and am hoping someone here might be able to read old scripts, I was told the right character is 松, and that the left character has 人(亻) as the left radical. Any help or guidance in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: seal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`人吕月松`

Since reading there right to left, which is

`松月侣`

Companion of Pine tree and the Moon

Comment: Btw, the font is called ```篆书``` , check the link: [wiki 篆书](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AF%86%E4%B9%A6)

Comment: Thank you so much for translating!

Comment: You are welcome, @amadeus